# Nagini or Naga kanya worship

Tags: naga

Are there any references related to worship of female Nagas (Naginis, Naga kanyas, etc.)?
How does it differ from Naga (male) worship?

Comment: Bengalis, Maithilis & Axomiyas don't revere nagas, instead they worship Manasa as the presiding deity of snakes. Manasa is identified as the mother of Astika named Jaratkaru who was married to sage Jaratkaru. So Manasa can be considered as a nagini by those who don't adore her (although for those who worship her, the term nagini is rather pejorative, since they refer to her as a devi). Manasa's worship is a typical Tantrika Shakta ceremony, albeit with some uniqueness. Some people (especially Bengali Hindus from areas like Noakhali & Chattagrama in Bangladesh) do even sacrifice goats to her.